# Google oAuth Login Prompt, redirect to download playstore app after Success

Tags: php, android, oauth, google-play

I visited the website getpocket.com, and on the login page, I signed up+logged in using my Google account.

I was prompted through a popup window to login via Google oAuth, and after granting successfully granting the scopes 'profile+email', it redirects me to another Google page if I'd like to download the app on my device.

'Would you also like to install * on your Android device?'

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiL3Z.png).

My question is, is this possible through the Google oAuth library, or does it simply manually redirect to the download app page after successful oauth perms?

Answer (score 1):

Found this information helpful:

https://developers.google.com/+/features/play-installs
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/android-app-installs